# Proof of Jordan curve theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Is it possible for the following to be proof for Jordan curve theorem:

Given the distance function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{
|x_2-x_1|^2 + |y_2-y_1|^2}$), and $\varepsilon > 0$, let $X$, the inside of a topological circle with center $y$, be defined as $(x|d(x,y)<\varepsilon)$. You may define the outside of this circle, named the set $Y$ as $(x|d(x,y) > \varepsilon)$. The set Z, the outline of this circle is defined by $(x|d(x,y) = \varepsilon)$. This splits the circle into two parts, interior and exterior, or $X$ and $Y$, respectively, with a boundary of $Z$.

If you could prove homeomorphism between these circles and all Jordan curves (proving all Jordan curves have an interior and exterior) would this be a valid proof?

Comment: Would this proof work for a pathological curve like the Koch Snowflake?

Comment: The existence of a homeomorphism between the circle and a Jordan curve says nothing about the complements of these curves in the plane. (The existence of knot theory, which is about circles embedded in three-dimensional space, is a witness to this fact.) OTOH, if you talk about homeomorphisms of the plane to itself mapping a circle onto an arbitrary Jordan curve, you'd be right, but then you are proving a much stronger result than the Jordan curve theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jordan-Schoenflies theorem states that the inside and outside of a Jordan curve are homeomorphic to the inside and outside of a standard circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You can read more in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-06/S0002-9939-1951-0046635-9/S0002-9939-1951-0046635-9.pdf).

Comment: It should be noted this doesn't hold in $\mathbb R^3$ - horned sphere.

Comment: If you proved this would this prove be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, @finap. But it's very hard to prove!

Comment: Thanks, although this still does not answer the question. Proving the Jordan Schoenflies theorem with the proof (stated in my question), would it be valid proof for the Jordan Curve theorem

Comment: The Jordan-Schoenflies theorem is an improvement on the JCT. In proving JST you would probably just end up proving the JCT along the way.

Comment: @JamesHines What if you proved all Jordan curves are a bijection from a circle?